# Time-dependent effects: tt in coxph()

Tags: survival, cox-model

I have 2 questions:

1. Why doesn't the 'tt' option in Coxph() in R estimate both a linear and a quadratic effect when you include "tt=function(x,t,...) x * I(t^2)" or "tt=list(function(x,t,...)x * t,function(x,t,...)x * I(t^2))" ? All I see in the output is tt(var), instead of tt(var * time) and tt(var * time^2).
2. How do I specify different time effects for different variables? After defining 'tt' I can only apply it to variables as a whole, so var1 is forced to have the same time interaction as var2. I may want one to be linear and the other quadratic, for example.

This may be mostly a programming question but it's possible I'm misunderstanding a concept related to time-dependent effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a `tt()` term is an attempt to fit a functional form that isn't constant in time for a predictor's coefficient, it doesn't make sense to have multiple `tt()` terms for the same predictor in the model. What you want is a single time-varying adjustment to what the predictor (without the extra time dependence) would provide.

In fact, R won't even let you do that. This quote from Section 5 of the [time-dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) answers your questions:

> If there are multiple `tt()` terms in the formula, then the `tt` argument should be a list of functions with the requisite number of elements. One footnote to this, however, is that you cannot have a formula like `log(bili) + tt(age) + tt(age)`. The reason is that the R formula parser removes redundant terms before the result even gets to the `coxph` function.

You can specify different `tt()` functions for different predictors in a list of functions, but I think that you have to have the order within the list in the same order as the `tt()` terms appear in the formula. If the number of `tt()` terms and the number of elements of the list of `tt()` functions doesn't agree, the software might silently choose just the first element of the list.

As I understand it, a standard polynomial in a `tt()` function won't result in separate coefficient estimates for each polynomial term. If you want a flexible fit for the time course, recent versions of the `survival` package provide the `nsk()` function that you can incorporate into a `tt()` function to allow for a regression spline fit. See Section 4.2 of the vignette. That returns separate coefficients associated with spline terms: "the coefficients are the predicted values at knots 2, 3, . . . - the predicted value at knot 1."

Splines are much more reliable than standard polynomials for regression modeling, unless you have a strong theoretical reason for a particular polynomial form. I can't think of how you would have such a theoretical justification for a single polynomial for the time course of a Cox model's regression coefficient.